# I need your help about read_fwf in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The example of text file is picture
[image]

According to file, the direction of data will be changed after the word 'chapter'
In the other word, Direction of reading is changed horizontal to vertical.

In order to solve this big problem, I find read_fwf in pandas module and apply it but failed.

```
linefwf = pandas.read_fwf('File.txt', widths=[33,33,33], header=None, nwors = 3)
```

The gap between categories(Chapter, Title, Assignment) is 33.

But the command(linefwf) prints all of pages line which includes horizontal categories such as Title, Date, Reservation as well as blank lines.

Please, I want to know 'How to export vertical data only'

Comment: Can you post raw input data rather than an image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me take a stab in the dark: you wish to turn this table into a column (aka "vertical category"), ignoring the other columns?

I didn't have your precise text, so I guesstimated it. My column widths were different than yours (`[11,21,31]`) and I omitted the `nwors` argument (you probably meant to use `nrows`, but it's superfluous in this case). While the column spec isn't very precise, a few seconds of fiddling left me with a workable `DataFrame`:

[image]

This is pretty typical of read-in datasets. Let's clean it up slightly, by giving it real column names, and taking out the separator rows:

```py
df.columns = list(df.loc[0])
df = df.ix[2:6]
```

This has the following effect:

[image]

Leaving us with `df` as:

[image]

We won't take the time to reindex the rows. Assuming we want the value of a column, we can get it by indexing:

```py
df['Chapter']
```

Yields:

```
2    1-1
3    1-2
4    1-3
5    1-4
6    1-5
Name: Chapter, dtype: object
```

Or if you want it not as a `pandas.Series` but a native Python `list`:

```py
list(df['Chapter'])
```

Yields:

```py
['1-1', '1-2', '1-3', '1-4', '1-5']
```

Comment: Oh my pandas god!! I understand that read_fwf change the text file to DataFrame after your answer!!! In my Korean book, there is no explain about Ix or lox method, but, after your visualized explain, I can understand about  pandas easily!! Thank you so much !!!

Comment: A simple way to think about `.loc` is that it's the "location" of the data. It lets you use an index (e.g. row names) that are different from Python's standard integer based indexing. `.ix` is actual integer-based indexing. I mixed-and-matched those two styles of access, which is pretty common. It takes a lot of time with the [indexing tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html) and trial-and-error to really "get" pandas selections.

Comment: I`m sorry to mark answer correct lately.  After finishing this work, I will try to study about pandas detail again (Actually, I major in management/finance). I think that python provides infinite tool for user. Your answer is really really helpful to me.  Thank you!

Comment: May I ask one more question?. My purpose is ,by taking out the data frame`(.ix)` from original total data frame, to construct other new data frame via concat or append. [link](http://i.imgur.com/ZXsqN6q.png). After running this file, `frame` in code is empty. Should I find another way?

Comment: Not sure I totally understand the question. But, many pandas operations create copies of the data. In this case, `df = df.ix[2:6]` does replace existing data. But you could just as well say `dnew = df.ix[2:6]`. Then you would have `dnew` with just the desired rows. `df` would be exactly as it was. `.ix` is not destructive. Some operations (e.g.  `.shift()`) are, but indexing almost never modifies the existing data.

Comment: OMG! I solve it by adding each data frame to empty list and by using pd.concat method . It takes 2days to solve this problem T_T. Thank you Jonathan !! Good luck :P for weekend just 3days left

Comment: pandas can be a little overwhelming at first. Take heart. It gets easier.